# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle11gDialect

Tags: java, hibernate

Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle11gDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

The configuration in application.properties file is

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
spring.datasource.username=bms
spring.datasource.password=system
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle11gDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

How to resolve this problem?
I have tried but it's not working

Comment: Use `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`; see the duplink for the explanation.